# My Materialize css sidenav hamburger menu doesn't work when I navigate to a React component using Link or NavLink

Tags: reactjs, materialize, sidenav

On mobile view whenever i navigate to a React component using Link or NavLink and the browser doesn't refresh my materialize css sidenav hamburger menu will becomes still and un-clickable but when I reload the page the sidenav hamburger menu will become clickable again. I know this is not a good user experience for my mobile user. I have tried using anchor tag instead but the purpose of building a single page application will be defeated if on every click the browser reloads. Any help, clue or suggestion will be appreciated.
Here is what i have tried:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.jpg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="logo192.jpg" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">


    <title>My Website</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

   <!-- Import JQuery -->
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

   <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.sidenav').sidenav();
      $('.datepicker').datepicker();
      $('.modal').modal();
      $('.materialboxed').materialbox();
    });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

navbar.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import '../../myStyles/main.css' //my custom css file


const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <div>
        <nav className="link-nav">
            <div className="nav-wrapper">

            <ul className="center hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><Link className="link-font-size" to='/'>HOME</Link></li>
                <li><Link className="link-font-size" to='/about'>About</Link></li>
                <li><Link className="link-font-size" to='/contact'>Contact</Link></li>
                <li><Link className="link-font-size" to='/login'>Login</Link></li>
                <li><Link className="link-font-size" to='/signup'>Sign Up</Link></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <ul id='mobile-sidenav-menu' className="sidenav">
                <li><Link to="#" className="sidenav-close right pink-text lighten-1">X</Link></li>  <li><Link className="link-font-size" to='/'>HOME</Link></li>
                <li><Link className="link-font-size" to='/about'>About</Link></li>
                <li><Link className="link-font-size" to='/contact'>Contact</Link></li>
                <li><Link className="link-font-size" to='/login'>Login</Link></li>
                <li><Link className="link-font-size" to='/signup'>Sign Up</Link></li>
         </ul>
          <a to="#" className="sidenav-trigger" data-target="mobile-sidenav-menu" >
                <i className="material-icons">menu</i>
            </a>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it help to put the hamburger inside the navbar, as per the [materializecss docs](https://materializecss.com/navbar.html/#mobile-collapse)?

```
<nav className="link-nav">
     <div className="nav-wrapper">
        <a to="#" className="sidenav-trigger" data-target="mobile-sidenav-menu" ><i className="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <ul className="center hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><Link className="link-font-size" to='/'>HOME</Link></li>
            <li><Link className="link-font-size" to='/about'>About</Link></li>
            <li><Link className="link-font-size" to='/contact'>Contact</Link></li>
            <li><Link className="link-font-size" to='/login'>Login</Link></li>
            <li><Link className="link-font-size" to='/signup'>Sign Up</Link></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<ul id='mobile-sidenav-menu' className="sidenav">
    <li><Link to="#" className="sidenav-close right pink-text lighten-1">X</Link></li>  <li><Link className="link-font-size" to='/'>HOME</Link></li>
    <li><Link className="link-font-size" to='/about'>About</Link></li>
    <li><Link className="link-font-size" to='/contact'>Contact</Link></li>
    <li><Link className="link-font-size" to='/login'>Login</Link></li>
    <li><Link className="link-font-size" to='/signup'>Sign Up</Link></li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT:**

Vanilla JS initialisation:

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
    var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems);
  });
```

**RE PROJECT SETUP**

Checkout this article. Matt has the component set up like so:

```
 import React from 'react';

 import 'materialize-css/js/waves.js'
 import 'materialize-css/js/buttons.js'
 import 'materialize-css/js/carousel.js'
 import 'materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss'


class App extends React.component {

    componentDidMount() {

        const elems = window.document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
        const options = {};
        window.M.Carousel.int(elems, options);
    }

    render(){...}

}
```

This may shed some light into it...?

https://medium.com/@mattdlockyer/youre-using-materialize-css-wrong-470b593e78e9

Comment: It doesn't, the sidenav still behave the same way @Doughballs

Comment: I wonder if you need to re-init sidenav() after each navigation? Seems superflous to me. But if the page has re-rendered, the sidenav is technically a new dom element that M doesn't know about? Dynamically added elements always have to be re-initialised in Materialize. Try it, if it works I'll update my answer. So I guess on each render of the nav, you would run a fresh $('.sidenav').sidenav();

Comment: How do I re-init sidenav() in a React component since I am using Materialize CDN?

Comment: These are you initialisations:

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.sidenav').sidenav();
      $('.datepicker').datepicker();
      $('.modal').modal();
      $('.materialboxed').materialbox();
    });
  </script> You are using CDN for the base materialize, but all inits are called in your custom JS.

Comment: please can you elaborate more on this "all inits are called in your custom JS" ?

Comment: Ok, you are serving the base materialize js file via cdn, which is totally fine. This can be served once. Initializations are what some components need to actually work. If you don't run the function $('.sidenav').sidenav(), then your sidenav will not work. So you run this inside a custom javascript file, or in between script tags, and usually you only need to do this once per site. But my theory is that after a navigation action, the sidenav is being re-rendered - is that correct? This would explain why it's stopped working - it has been re-added to the dom and the init has already run.

Comment: I get this error "$ is not defined" whenever I try to initialize the $('.sidenav').sidenav() in any file other than the index.html file in the public folder @Doughballs

Comment: Updated answer with vanilla js initialisation - "$ is not defined" is a jQuery probem.

Comment: I was able to resolve the M is not defined by doing this in the navbar component but the hamburger icon is still not working on any page I use Link or NavLink to navigate to:


`componentDidMount() {
        const M = window.M;
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('sidenav');
        var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems, {});
        });
    }`

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('sidenav') should be document.querySelector('.sidenav')

Comment: Just tried it and it still didn't work @Sean Doherty